# How to solve "Double free for ptr 0x7f7c33808200" in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, malloc

I have a Ruby on Rails API application on macOS Sonoma, x86 intel i7.

I can start the server using `rails s`. When I hit my endpoint, it logs the following:

```
Started POST "/v1/login" for ::1 at 2023-12-13 19:38:46 +0700
ruby(5405,0x70000e8b9000) malloc: double free for ptr 0x7f7c33808200
ruby(5405,0x70000e8b9000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
zsh: abort      rails server
```

I already performed `bundle update`, `bundle clean`, `bundle install` again. I also restarted my laptop, and it stills occurred.

How do I solve this error?

Comment: You're not using `async-pool` v0.3.9 by any chance are you?

Comment: how to use this @smathy ?

Comment: Check the output of `bundle list`.

Answer (score 9):

To [revert to version 3.1.4](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/155651#issuecomment-1828065418) execute the following commands:

```bash
> brew unlink openssl@3
```

```bash
> curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/e68186ba5a05a6ea9a30d6c7744de9a46bd3aadd/Formula/o/openssl@3.rb > openssl@3.rb && brew install openssl@3.rb
```

> Done!!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Definitely could use more context...

Answer (score 3):

If you installed postgres on a mac with Homebrew,

> Homebrew's Postgreses now are compatible with openssl 3.2, please run brew upgrade postgresql@ or brew upgrade libpq to get the fixed version.

Source: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/155651#issuecomment-1830261308